# escape hyphen (-) on search

Tags: php

How can modify below `if statement` to get the same search result  when i enter R1 and R-1 most my data contains `-` Forexample `SUPER POWER DRIVE RADIAL R-1` on the current search I can get all result containing R-1 but i want also show all results containing R-1 when i enter R1 as a search key.

`$txtsize  is search textbox`

```
 if (($txtsize!="") && (preg_match("/\b".preg_quote($txtsize,'/')."\b/i", $row['Tire_Size']) || ($row['Tire Size']==$txtsize)))
```

Thanks
Kinfe

Comment: Have you considered using `str_replace` to remove `-`s from your search items?

Comment: where's the rest of the code ?

Comment: You are not getting at the heart of the problem. Does the problem lie in the input date or in the data structure (which you do not comment upon) in which the search "dictionary" is stored?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), i.e.:

```
$txtsize = str_replace("R-1", "R1", $txtsize);
```

---